# При первом запуске Symfony появляется ошибка

Tags: php, symfony

При первом запуске Symfony появляется ошибка. Кто может сталкивался?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже контейнер как то криво собрался, что конечно же достаточно странно. Попробуйте удалить вручную содержимое папки cache и собственно зайдите еще раз по адресу, кэш в деве соберется автоматически. Возможно все встанет на свои места.

Comment: К сожаление не сработало. Но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. До этого проект запускалca из каталога d:\OSPanel\domains\symfony_proj и ничего не работало. Перенес в корень диска D:\symfony_proj и все окей, работает.